# UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: not working on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm creating a `tableView` which contains the images from gallery picked by the user, then I take the selected `imagePath` to place it on an `UIImageView`.

To set an iOS gallery image in a `UIImageView`,
I'm using:

```
NSString *imgPath = @"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/105APPLE/IMG_5903.JPG";//Hardcoded path just for test, image actually exists on iOS device

self.imgViewContainer.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imgPath];
```

This code which works on Simulator.

I tested on a real device and I noticed that the `UIImageView` is empty after execute the above code.

Is there a way to achieve this using a real device?

Comment: Why do you expect that path be valid on a real iOS device? Why does it start with `@`?

Comment: Sorry! It was the @ of the String, question edited... I'm using that path just for a test, the image exists

Comment: 1. Does that path actually exist on the real iOS device? 2. Apps are sandboxes and can't read files outside of its own sandbox on a real device.

Comment: Yep, It actually exists on the real device, but this can be achieved even I manage lot of images? or some code to test it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to app sandboxing, your app does not have permission to view the contents of `/var/mobile/Media` (or really any subdirectory of `/var/`).  Consider the code below:

```
do {
    let fileList = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

`contentsOfDirectory(atPath:)` with throw an error with these details:

> ```
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “DCIM” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/, NSUserStringVariant=(
>     Folder
> ), NSUnderlyingError=0x170045700 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
> ```

This example is in Swift, but the equivalent Objective-C code would have the same error.

There is no way around this (unless your are using a jailbroken device running your application as the root user).  Use `UIImagePickerController` to ask the user for an image.

Comment: Wish i saw that before spending time on this :D thanks mate !